# files zipped using function not naming correctly

Tags: bash, variable, function, zip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm probably missing something basic with bash function variable syntax here.

My understanding of the zip command's syntax is that it's `zip newfilename.zip filetobezipped`. So I want my function to zip the specified folder and all its contents, and I want the result, zipped folder to be named the same name as the contents, just with .zip added. Then I copy that over to my windows directory and delete it from the linux directory.

To be clear, if the file I want zipped is called "something", then I want the zipped version to be named "something.zip".

However, this function produces a hidden zip file, `.zip` with no letters before the period. So it seems my variable $1 is not being passed into the function correctly.

```
params: $1: filename, $2: week_x, $3: day_y
hwcopy() {
    zip -r $1.zip $1
    cp $1.zip /mnt/c/Users/myName/Desktop/homework/$2/$3
    rm -r $1.zip
}
```

How I called it (from within the parent directory): `$ hwcopy file_folder_name/ week_x day_5`

Comment: [Quote right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Answer (score 0):

I realized after testing more that the issue was the way I called it.

`zip file_name/.zip file_name` won't work, but `zip file_name.zip file_name` will work.

So I instead referred to it as `${1%/}.zip` inside the function, to cut off the slash character.